# Fargo season 2 episode 8: is the letter on the refrigerator anachronistic?

Tags: fargo-tv

At about ten minutes into Fargo season 2 episode 8 ("Loplop"), Hanzee sees (and takes) from the Blumquist's refrigerator a letter from a hotel confirming Constance Heck's reservation:

[image: Thank you for booking a room at the Southnick Hotel]

This does not look to me at all like a form letter that would be produced in 1979: note the scaled fonts, including scaling on the superscripts for things like "March 24<sup>th</sup>" that are typical of typesetting systems or laser printers (which were very large and expensive and not in common use at the time). I wouldn't expect to see letters like this for another ten years or more.

Is there some other system from this time period that would be producing letters like this, or am I wrong that businesses were not producing letters like this in 1979? Or is this truly anachronistic?

Comment: The title font might be pre-printed by a print shop, and the hotel only prints the text underneath. And I believe electronic typewriters had "letter" heads for common symbols like superscript "st", "nd", "rd", and "th". Same for the "fi" ligature ("ﬁ" in "confirmed"). But I might be mistaken.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Nice catch on the `ﬁ` ligature! I do recall using proportional-spacing typewriters (electric, not electronic) back in the early '80s, and it's certainly possible that they had the superscripts and ligatures and the like.

Comment: But your comment made me realise one of the things that rings untrue about this that I'd not consciously appreciated before: the heading and the body text _are the exact same font._  I never saw a Helvetica-like font on the proportional-spacing typewriters I used, but while that's not a good indication that it didn't exist, the use of the same font for larger size pre-printed letterhead and smaller size typed-out copy kinda screams, "laser printer" to me.

Comment: Actually, if I am not mistaken, the use of sans-serif fonts for body text seems to be a rather recent phenomenon. For a long time, it was believed that you need serifs to create a "virtual baseline" to guide the reader so they don't accidentally jump to the wrong line when scanning back from the end of the line to the beginning of the next. This has only been changed after switching from print to digital media where you can afford to increase the line spacing without wasting paper. (It is no coincidence that some of the serif-heavy fonts were designed for newspapers, e.g. Times (New Roman))

Comment: Yeah I don’t recall ever seeing a font like that on paper before laser printers.